# Returning an array elements using an index

Tags: objective-c

This is the default code that comes part of a page base app  .
_pageData basically takes a number in and returns a month .
I would like to do something quite simple but is giving me grief in Objective C . I would basically like to declare an immutable Array with strings and instead of _pageData converting a number into a month, I would like use this same number as an index in the array and return the matching string .

I hope it makes sense .

EDIT (more code)

```
@interface ModelController()
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageData;
@end

@implementation ModelController

@synthesize pageData = _pageData;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Create the data model.
//        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//        _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy];

        NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
        NSString *item = [items objectAtIndex:1];
        _pageData = item;


    return self;
}

- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{   
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];

    dataViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
    return dataViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully this snippet helps.  You can create an array from static strings and then index into to read one of them.

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSString *item = [items objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"item=%@", item);
```

concerning your month example, if it's months be careful about getting it out of a array of static strings.  For an example that's fine but for a real app that may get localized, it's better to get it from date objects.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet , it definitely helps, but I'm now getting "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray *__strong' from 'NSString *__strong' when I replace  _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy] by _pageData = item;

Comment: we might need to see more code to help see what you're assigning.

Comment: perhaps you can edit your question above and edit an "Additional Info:" header with the additional code.   It looks like your trying to assign a string to an array.

Comment: I edited the question, before we had _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy]; I assume it returned a String, it probably didn`t hence the error

Comment: OK - so what is _pageData declared as in the header?  It needs to be an NSArray* And also, what type is dataViewController.dataObject? It needs to be NSString*

Comment: ah ! _pageData is an NSArray but dataViewController.dataObject is @property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject; !